# Setting PHP Class variable with a variable call

Tags: php

I am modifying a script that I bought and I am having trouble making the Database name variable that is set in the Database class be the result of the variable I construct above it.  I need the $dbName variable to be set to the combination of "mmo_" appended to the variable $username that I get from my database.  The name of the database should be "mmo_school" with school being the $username variable that is pulled from database.  However, it fails unless I put the text of the variable in single quotes after $dbName = .  But I need the database name to be dynamically set based on which user is using the script.  I hope that this makes sense and I really appreciate your help!!

```
$username = "school";
$newname = "mmo_" . $username;  **// the results of this would be "mmo_school"**

class Database 
{
    private static $dbName = $newname ; 
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'username';
    private static $dbUserPassword = 'password';

    private static $cont  = null;

    public function __construct() {
        exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }
    public static function connect() {
        // One connection through whole application
        if ( null == self::$cont ) {      
            try {
                self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);  
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());  
            }
        } 
        return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect() {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
```

if I type in $dbName = 'mmo_school' ;  THIS WORKS.
if I try to use the variable I create as shown above...IT DOESN'T!!!

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!

Comment: Instead of `public function __construct() { exit('Init function is not allowed'); }` Just make the constructor private. `private function __construct(){ blah }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a public static method to set the host, username, password, and etc. Also, i would change your constructor to private not public.

```
Database::setDB('mmo_' . $username);
// or
Database::setConnectInfo('mmo_' . $username, 'some host', $username, 'some password');
$db = Database::connect();

class Database 
{
    private static $dbName = $newname ; 
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'username';
    private static $dbUserPassword = 'password';

    private static $cont  = null;

    private function __construct() {
        exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function setDB($dbName){
        self::$dbName = $dbName;
    }

    // or use this function 

    public static function setConnectInfo($dbName, $dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbUserPassword){
        self::$dbName = $dbName;
        self::$dbHost = $dbHost;
        self::$dbUsername = $dbUsername;
        self::$dbUserPassword = $dbUserPassword;
    }

    public static function connect() {
        // One connection through whole application
        if ( null == self::$cont ) {      
            try {
                self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);  
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());  
            }
        } 
        return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect() {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do all in a single method?

Comment: I was just giving the dude options/examples in case he didn't to set everything with one call.

Comment: Fair enough. @musixweb You could do everything in one call and get rid of the static properties. I don't think you would need to store the private properties after the connection is made.

Comment: in my comment below I tried something that didn't work...any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In your class you have to call $newname as a global variable. With this minor change your code should work.

```
$username = "school";
$newname = "mmo_" . $username;  **// the results of this would be "mmo_school"**

class Database {

private static $dbName = "" ; 
private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
private static $dbUsername = 'username';
private static $dbUserPassword = 'password';

private static $cont  = null;

function __construct($init_parameter) {
global $newname;
    $this->$dbName = $newname;
}
public static function connect() {
    // One connection through whole application
    if ( null == self::$cont ) {      
        try {
            self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);  
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }
    } 
    return self::$cont;
}

public static function disconnect() {
    self::$cont = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much...but unfortunately I uploaded that and tried it and that didn't work.  In fact Dreamweaver gives me a *syntax error, unexpected global (T_GLOBAL)* on the global line and then still a *syntax error, unexpected variable (T_VARIABLE)* on the next line.

Comment: You can also modify the construct function. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

because single quotes don't do variable expansion - use double quotes

```
$var = 'dingo';

$name = 'xyz_$var';   // result 'xyz_$var'
$name = "xyz_$var";   // result 'xyz_dingo'
```